# How to show cyrillic (other utf) text in api response

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm building a ip location API that returns

```
{
    "city": "Research", 
    "country_code": "AU", 
    "country_name": "\u0410\u0432\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043b\u0438\u044f", 
    "ip": "1.1.1.1", 
    "location": "-37.7,145.1833", 
    "organisation": "", 
    "postal": "3095", 
    "region": "Victoria", 
    "time_zone": "Australia/Melbourne"
}
```

When language is set to `ru`, is there any way to pretty print the country name, so that it shows the cyrillic?

I would also like to render, Simplified Chinese and Japanese.

Comment: I'm using python for this, tagged it above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is who reads your text and under which encoding. 
Of course it is possible to create a Unicode text and put anything in there.
The question is, from the other end, is it possible to read it with no problem?

The way it is now it is guaranteed to work, no matter what the encoding is, because it is ASCII only.

Even if you convert back to unicode, which encoding would you prefer? UTF16 (Windows)? UTF8 (Unix)? 8-bit only? This is not a safe choice. The only safe choice (and the reason why is like this) is to leave it as is.

Why would you care for the visibility of an API result?

Comment: The suggestion is, I should just leave it to end users to be smart enough to decode this for themselves in their applications? Is there any way I could do this anyway?

Comment: Since it is an API, I believe the safest solution is to leave it as is. It would be at most compatible and the people to consume it know about it.

Comment: You could use a regex that matched on `'/\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/',` then convert (somehow) back to UTF.

Comment: Your right thanks. I'll leave it as is. I'd wanted to show off the multi-language functionality in screenshots for user tutorials.

Comment: For show off, just change it by hand. There are even viewers who parse your string and display UTF - it's all in the viewer.

Comment: @Panayotis JSON documents are Unicode and JSON strings inside are Unicode. Every reader must be provided with the encoding of the document (through HTTP response header Content-Type or otherwise). So, it seems your concern is over readers that won't follow the standards.

Comment: @TomBlodget Indeed in theory is as you said. But unfortunately we are not living in a perfect world. I've seen  situations that shouldn't be, but there are, since I myself I using the Greek alphabet and it is really a pain.